# Compare two xml elements of same parent node in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

```
<department>
    <employee name="ABC">
    <salary value="basic">5000</salary>
    <salary value="allowance">8000</salary>
    </employee>
    <employee name="XYZ">
    <salary value="basic">6000</salary>
    <salary value="allowance">3000</salary>
    </employee>
    </department>
```

How to get the employee names whose allowance is greater than basic in powershell.

I have tried below but does not give me the result

```
$result= $xml |Select-Xml '//department'| 
ForEach{
$basic=$_.Node.employee.salary.value | where {$_.Node.employee.salary.value -eq 'basic'}
$allowance=$_.Node.employee.salary.value | where {$_.Node.employee.salary.value -eq 'allowance'}
if ($allowance -ge $basic)
{
$name=$_.Node.employee.name
}
}
echo $result
```

Comment: Change `$name=$_.Node.employee.name` -> `$_.Node.employee.name`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `Select-Xml`, you can do the following:

```
$node = $xml | Select-Xml -XPath "//department/employee[./salary[@value='basic'] < ./salary[@value='allowance']]"
$node.node.name # Output the employee name
```

See [XPath Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)) for xpath expression examples. See [Boolean, Comparison, and Set Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256081(v=vs.100)) for more information on XPath operators including the escaping of `<` and `>` where necessary.

Comment: Yes please, an XPath solution :-D <3

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PowerShell XML parser (`[XML]`) to create a XMLDocument:

```
$xml = [XML]'
    <department>
        <employee name="ABC">
            <salary value="basic">5000</salary>
            <salary value="allowance">8000</salary>
        </employee>
        <employee name="XYZ">
            <salary value="basic">6000</salary>
            <salary value="allowance">3000</salary>
        </employee>
    </department>'
```

Then it is as simple as:

```
$xml.Department.Employee | % {
    $allowance = [Int]($_.salary | ? {$_.value -eq 'allowance'}).'#text'
    $basic = [Int]($_.salary | ? {$_.value -eq 'basic'}).'#text'
    If ($allowance -ge $basic) {$Name = $_.name}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, $_.Node.employee.salary.value is just an array of strings, so the where cmd can't reference any properties, and $basic and $allowance end up being blank.  Also, the foreach only loops one time, because there's only one department.

This way, you're already piping in an array of employees, instead of the one department.  I also get the node property out of the way.  $basic and $allowance are still objects with value and #text properties.  I output the employee object that matches.   It's sort of like what you were trying to do.  The comparison has to be [int], or else '500' is greater than '4000'.

```
(Select-Xml /department/employee salary.xml).node |
ForEach {
  $basic = $_.salary | where value -eq basic
  $allowance = $_.salary | where value -eq allowance
  if([int]$allowance.'#text' -ge $basic.'#text') {
    $_ | select name, 
      @{n='basic'; e={$basic.'#text'}}, 
      @{n='allowance'; e={$allowance.'#text'}} 
  }
}


name basic allowance
---- ----- ---------
ABC  5000  8000
```